# Refrigerator water supply valve

Tags: plumbing, refrigerator

Can anyone tell me WHY all of the 'delivery' instructions say that the shutoff has to be within 6' of the refrigerator or they will not hook it up? And I mean the literature states they will not even leave it.

I intend to finish the basement - later. That means I can't 'hide' a shutoff valve in a ceiling. My only option is a laundry room which would place the shutoff approx 10' from the floor penetration. I do not want to put it behind the refrigerator or build it into the wall for logical reasons. The simplicity of connecting a braided line from a shutoff in the overhead laundry room is where it's at. They sell 20' braided water kits but you would never ever need one if shutoff was within 6'. Doesn't make sense.

I just haven't been able to find an explanation for the six foot "rule" anywhere. And since I can't seem to access the UPC online, I'm at a loss.

Comment: Run the plumbing, put a temporary valve in behind the refrigerator, when they leave, remove the temp valve and plumb as you had originally intended.

Answer (score 1):

It’s something put in by the underwriters to limit insurance liability for manufacturing defects the shut off needs to be readily accessible to turn off before it can do too much damage

Just tell them you don’t intend to hook it up to water your just using the fridge and freezer then how you hook it up is on you

Comment: Got it. I like the idea of a temp valve and have them hook it to make sure I don't have water spraying all over the back of the unit.